# counting how many checkbox are checked php/html

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Hi I am new with php and I was wondering how am i able to count how many `'checkbox'` are checked once I click on submit. 
For example:

```
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox1"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox2"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox3"/>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Give the checkboxes names as array like

```
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[]"/>
```

And after **submit** try like

```
$checked_arr = $_POST['checkbox'];
$count = count($checked_arr);
echo "There are ".$count." checkboxe(s) are checked";
```

**Note :** And based on the method that your form submit using...whether it is `$_GET` or `$_POST` you need to use `$_POST['checkbox']` for **POST** method and `$_GET['checkbox']` for the **GET** method.

Comment: This is probably correct answer because without using `name = "checkbox[]"` it needs to check multiple values.

Comment: What if, say the input type is a "number" input type

Comment: Hehe, it seems I should have just posted my answer rather than taking time to test it. Same answer as yours was. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$checkedBoxes = 0;

// Depending on the action, you set in the form, you have to either choose $_GET or $_POST
if(isset($_GET["checkbox1"])){
  $checkedBoxes++;
}
if(isset($_GET["checkbox2"])){
  $checkedBoxes++;
}
if(isset($_GET["checkbox3"])){
  $checkedBoxes++;
}
```

Comment: this is a fabulous one. a true PHP-way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox"/>
```

to check which boxes have been checked simply traverse through the chk[]
array like this:

```
$chk_array = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($chk_array as $chk_key => $chk_value)
{
print 'Checkbox Id:'. $chk_key . ' Value:'. $chk_value .'is
checked';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename the names and add values

```
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[]" value="1"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[]" value="2"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[]" value="3"/>
```

This way you will know not only number (which you don't actually need)

```
echo count($_POST['checkbox']);
```

but also have the actual selected values:

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val)
{
    echo "$val<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can achieve it:

`$("input:checkbox:checked").length`

This will return the number of checboxes checked.

And in php you'll need to pass it as an array.

`echo count($_POST['checkbox']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can set names for the checkboxes as an array:

```
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[1]"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[2]"/>
<input type = "checkbox" value = "box" name = "checkbox[3]"/>
```

and then you will have an array in PHP (`$_POST['checkbox']`):

```
echo count( $_POST['checkbox'] ); // this will give you the count
```

otherwise you can iterate over each one of them and increment a variable:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach( array('checkbox1', 'checkbox2', 'checkbox3') as $name ) {
  if( isset( $_POST[ $name ] ) {
     $counter++
  }
}
echo $counter;
```

Answer (score -1):

All boxes that are checked will be in the Request when u click submit.
In your case, if checkbox1 is checked u get:
"checkbox1=box"

If you use **GET** as the method it will look like: http://yoururl.com/yourcode.php?checkbox1=box and u can access it with $_GET['checkbox1']

If you use **POST** as the method you can access it with $_POST['checkbox1']

You can also check if the box is checked (and in the Request data) with isset($_POST['checkbox1'])