# Insert value of checkbox and number input into database

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

I tried combining two answers from here:
[counting how many checkbox are checked php/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572351/counting-how-many-checkbox-are-checked-php-html)
And here:
[validating input types "checkbox" and "number" php/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574626/validating-input-types-checkbox-and-number-php-html)

My goal is to count how many checkboxes were selected, and insert their values along with the number value in the number input.

I found various other posts about it, but couldn't figure out an answer.

Here is the code:

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
```

Then I have a for loop, where I create my table rows, with the checkboxes.
Where $id = $row[0] is updated on each loop, which is the id equivalent of my entry.
(The output of

```
echo '<td style="vertical-align: top;">' . $row[0] . '</td>';
```

Shows the id correctly)

```
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td style='vertical-align: top;'><input type='checkbox' name='choice[$id][id]' value='$id'></td>";
echo "<td style='vertical-align: top;'><input type='number' name='choice[$id][order]' size='20'></td>";
echo '</tr>';
echo '<b> <input type="submit" value="Insert"></b>';
```

Then, on the next page, I have this:

```
$var_checkbox=$_POST['choice'];
$sql_var_id = "SELECT id FROM custom_form WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM custom_form)";
$var_id_result = mysqli_query($link,$sql_var_id);
$var_id = mysqli_fetch_array($var_id_result);

        $count=count($var_checkbox[$var_id[0]]);

        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            if($var_checkbox[$i]!= NULL){

                $sql1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO custom_form_has_property (custom_form_id,property_id,field_order) VALUES ('%d','%d','%d');",
                    $var_id[0],
                    $var_checkbox[$var_id[0]][id],
                    $var_checkbox[$var_id[0]][order]
                );
                $result1 = mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
            }
        }
```

The problem is, that no values of checkboxes or numbers are inserted.

(As a side note, to try and be more specific)
If instead of matrixes, I use

```
   echo "<td style='vertical-align: top;'><input type='checkbox' name='choice[]' value='$row[0]'></td>";
   echo '<td style="vertical-align: top;"><input type="number" name="order[]" size="2"></td>';
```

And

```
    $var_checkbox=$_POST['choice'];
    $order = $_POST['order'];
```

Then

```
echo "Orders: $order[0],$order[1],$order[2],$order[3],$order[4],$order[5],$ordemr[6]";
echo "Choices: $var_checkbox[0],$var_checkbox[1],$var_checkbox[2],$var_checkbox[3],$var_checkbox[4],$var_checkbox[5],$var_checkbox[6]";
```

Will output

> Orders: 1,,2,,3,,Choices: 1,3,13,,,,

I need the choiced from the checkboxes to be somehow linked to the orders from the number field. And the only way to achieve that, is if they have the same name, but different indexes, which is why I have the matrix, in the first index, it's saved the id number, which is generated on each loop, and in the second, the actual name, which makes the distinction between them (id and order).

I tried various other things, but it all comes back to the same problem...
The value of order (number) is stored into the array, even when null, while the value of choices (checkbox) doesnt.
I could do an array_filter(), but there is no guarantee that the user will not input an order, while not ticking a choice checkbox.
If I would compare the length of choice with the length of order, after filtered, and if they output the same size, there is still no guarantee, that the user didnt check checkbox of line x, and added a value in the order field, on line y.

Maybe there is a way to pass unchecked values to the choice[] variable as null, the same way it happens in order[]?

Comment: You're presently mixing MySQL APIs `mysql_` and `mysqli_` which do not intermix with each other. You're looking to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` rather than `mysql_real_escape_string()`, where [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires DB connection be passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @Fred, he doesn't need to escape those at all, because they are numbers (see `%d`?).

Comment: I know, I have tried with both, but I had bad experiences with mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: Either way, if you're going to want to use `real_escape_string()`, you can't intermix APIs which is what you are doing right now.

Comment: Well it is working, I had used it elsewhere as well.
My problem is somewhere at the input names.

Comment: That still won't work. I said earlier *"requires DB connection be passed as the first parameter."* - You're not passing the connection to it. Please read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: What is this? `choice[.$id.]` ? what are the dots for? I believe this is the bug!

Comment: No, I tried both with and without dots, same result.

Comment: Where do your `$id` values come from on page 1?

Comment: From within the while cycle, that outputs my table.
$id = $row[0]
The $id value is correct, because I previously (not shown in the code), I output $row[0], which shows the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

What is this? `choice[.$id.]` ? what are the dots for?

I believe this is the bug!
You probably were trying to concatenate `$id` into the string before and just forgot to remove them?

Corrected line:

```
echo "<td style='vertical-align: top;'><input type='checkbox' name='choice[$id][id]' value='$id'></td>";
```

Comment: This is the output of echo "Choices: $var_checkbox[1][id],$var_checkbox[1][order] (also removed the dots): "Choices: Array[id],Array[order]"

Answer (score 0):

there are some way to do this ..

1. you have to count total no of selected check box via jQuery and set those value in hidden field at view page on each check box check or on form submit
2. you have to take counter on insert part and save the ids and at last update ids value with counter value in database ....

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something similar... Count the total numbers of rows. Add the value via a hidden input.
Then for each loop, until i < count, check if the checkbox has been selected, and if yes, then add the values to the DB. However, I think this overcomplicates things...

Comment: why u use i<count ?? you run loop for total no of check box then directly use counter (hidden field value) for store total no of check check box....

Comment: and the checkbox name "choice[]" will only post into the array the values of the checked boxes.

Comment: so you have to just count choice[] it will give only total no of selected check box and store that value ....

Comment: Currently, I only count the boxes that are checked. The problem is that the input type number, with name order[] will output an array that has both the null values and the entered values

Comment: Another thing would be to force the user, if he has values in order[] field, then he must also have values in choice[] field. And then do an array clean up of the order[] field, leaving me only the values that are not null. So then, the index that corresponds to choice[] will also correspond to order[].